# Passport stamped with correct class (B2) at Port of entry, but doesn't have admit until date mentioned on the stamp. Is it ok?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I just landed in US on a B1/B2 Visa. The CBP officer at the Port of entry asked me how long I want to stay and I replied 180 days. He then stamped my passport with today's date and the right class B2. However I noticed that the admit until date is blank and the CBP officer didn't write anything on it. I'm not able to get my latest I-94 from the CBP website so I don't know how long I can stay in the country. How do I get this fixed?

Comment: Are you still at the airport? Ask where the CBP office is and go there. Or just ignore it, is pretty common to not have an expiration given.

Comment: I'm not at the airport. While there I tried asking a couple of officers who I thought were CBP, but they said they weren't sure and didn't know where to go for this query. One of them asked me to check I-94, but unfortunately the website isn't updated with my latest I-94 yet. Do I need to visit the deferred inspections site to get this fixed?

Comment: Unlikely you need to do anything, just enjoy your visit and check the I-94 site in a few days.

Comment: So what happened?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.